# Is it bad practice to instantiate a class on the same line that you call a method on it?

Tags: .net, memory-management, garbage-collection

If I only need to instantiate a class to call a single method on it and then be done with it, I like to do it in a single line like so,

```
string result = new MyClass().GetResult();
```

Instead of doing something like,

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
string result = myClass.GetResult();
```

It is my understanding that the same thing is going on behind the scenes in terms of memory allocation and subsequent cleanup. Is this really the case or is there a difference? And if so, is one more efficient than the other?

**EDIT:**

Making the method static, like many of you have suggested, is a good solution. I am working with a class that someone else created that I am unable to refactor or change at the moment. So for this kind of situation, is there any difference in instantiating inline or on a separate line?

**EDIT:**

Does the answer to this question vary depending on the number of resources that the class maintains (from Blam & BenCr's comments below)?

Comment: It seems like you should make GetResult a static method to me.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.  But let's say for this example there is a non-default constructor on the class and you just needed to access the single method and then be done with it.

Comment: Does MyClass() implement IDisposabe?  Does it hold resources that can be released?

Comment: I _think_ it depends on the scope of myClass, and how much internal state MyClass holds. I _think_ it's possible that there might only be a very small difference and it's possible that there might be a large difference. I'm interested in finding out the actual answer.

Comment: That's a good point about resources and internal state, Blam & BenCr.  I would like to know, too, so I'm going to add that to the question.

Comment: SO is not for a general discussion of garbage collection and dispose.  Even if you don't have access to the source code you can determine if it implements IDisposable.  The using statement is a way to call dispose.  If the object does not really dispose properly then nothing you can do about it.

Comment: This seems to be quite a specific and answerable question to me.

Comment: @smudgedlens: Jens' answer should answer your question. There is no *semantic* difference between the two code snippets that you posted. If `MyClass` implements `IDisposable`, then both options are unacceptable since you are not disposing of the instance. Otherwise, there is no difference and the first option (to me) is more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>It should actually be more efficient to use the one-liner, since the runtime has one less local variable to keep track of for purposes of garbage collection.</strike> **Edit:** Incorrect, see Adam's reply below. My original point still stands, tough, the effect (if any) should be negligible.

But the real question is: Why is GetResult() not a static function? That would avoid the whole instantiation completely.

Comment: The first part of your answer is incorrect, as the GC tracks *references*, not *variables* (variables only determine the reachability of a reference). The number of references--1--is the same and the instance itself will follow the same garbage collection path in both cases.

Comment: I don't understand your comment Adam, please can you explain it further or provide a link? How can a reference exist if it isn't assigned to a variable? There's no way to reference the myClass instance after the first call to the GetResults method?

Comment: @BenCr: The reference exists after the `newobj` call. It immediately falls out of scope (and thus is inaccessible) after the subsequent `callvirt` call. The same happens with the variable. There is a syntactic but basically no semantic difference.

Comment: @Adam: You are right, of course. The reference falls out of scope, variable or not. I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see anything regarding your question in the [C# coding conventions.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff926074.aspx)

My personal preference would be the latter example you have given. I think that it would allow for improved readability of your code.

However, if you're instantiating a class just to get a single value from it, maybe it'd be better to rethink how that class is designed. Your GetResult() method should probably be static?

Answer (score 0):

This only applies if the class implements IDisposable.
If you are looking for efficient use of single method and be done with it then neither.
MyClass() will not be disposed until it falls out of scope.

```
using (myClass = new MyClass()) 
{
    string result = myClass.GetResult();
}
```

[using Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Consider static methods and classes

[Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Garbage Collection is a wide topic.
You stated it is not your code but if you write code that holds resources here is some guidance.

[IDisposable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

Comment: Please note: This is only required if `MyClass` actually implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: Isn't this only applicable if MyClass implements IDisposable?

Comment: Agree on IDisposable will add to answer.